# using rules module : how i can adding page with the name of text field form when i click in the button

Tags: nodes, entities, rules, webforms

I want to automatically create a page had like name the one that I put in the fields: title of the node,
here is the image:
[image]

the steps that I want:

1 . enter a name of the node (example: Name of node).

2 . click the button BTTN.

3 . and when I click a page is going to automatically create a page as the name (example: Name of node).

I know how to add a page automatically (using rules), but I can not seem to give the name that I want 
how i can add a page with the name of the text field?

Comment: can you show the Rules set up you have now so we can see where the problem may be

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "name of the node"? Is it the title, or the URL? I guess it's not the name of the author, or the "machine name" of any of the fields that you want to contain some that that were submitted. Also, please try to clarify the details in your question so that it matches what we can see in your screenprint: what does testtesttest refer to? What is the usage of that field with title "Title of node:"?